# Cannot POST /contact.php

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form on my website and I get the "Cannot POST /contact.php" error.

This is my form at html page:

```
<form role="form" action="contact.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputName">Nom</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="InputName" placeholder="Nom" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputEmail">Sujet</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="subject" placeholder="Sujet" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputMessage">Message</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputReal">5 + 10? (Spam Checker)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="human" class="form-control" name="InputReal" id="InputReal" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">
</form>
```

And then I tried my PHP code (contact.php). I don't know if there is something wrong as I am very bad at PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'myemail@email.com';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '15') {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '15') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
?>
```

If anyone who understands PHP could help, that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is contact.php located in the same folder?

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Your spam checker can be bypassed, by the way.

Comment: What is the http error?

Comment: @rajeshujade `Cannot POST /contact.php`

Comment: @StijnBernards yes, contact.php is in the same folder.

Comment: I mean http error ? Is it 404 or something else? It will help to understand its apache or php problem

Comment: @rajeshujade It says 404 Not Found. But I don't get it, because the file is located on the same folder.

Comment: Can you please tell me your domain url & the url where you submitting the form

Comment: @user1879457 add a / before contact.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by [Sakthi Karthik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26056240/2521769), you need to check the directory/path of `contact.php`.

Also in the condition you should check:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'] && $human == '15')
```

Likewise:

```
else if(isset($_POST['submit'] && $human != '15')
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `contact.php` file in same folder or not.
 you have missing tag `</form>`

Comment: I have the </form>. My bad copying, sorry. And contact.php is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running your web page in XAMP/htdocs/"your project folder"/contact.php

PHP is a server side language, and it needs to be run on server.

Start your XAMPP and make sure that Apache and MySQL are starded and running.