# Everytime I submit my form my PHP file does not post

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP, but I am working on a login system for this website.  I am currently working on the account creation page and I can not get the .php file to post to my database.  Can anyone out there give me a hand?  My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EDAViewer Login Console</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
           <div class="header">
               <header>
                   <img src="/Assets/BGLogo.png" alt="EDAViewer Logo">
                   <img src="/Assets/accountCreation.png" alt="Create Account" class="console-img">
               </header>
            </div>
            <div class="login-container">
                <fieldset class="login-form">

                    <form class="form" action="newAccount.php" method="POST">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" required>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="password" required>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label for="verify-password">Verify Password</label>
                                <input type="text" name="verify-password" required>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <footer>
            <p>Copyright &copy 2018 EDA Technologies, Ltd</p>
         </footer>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

here is the PHP:

```
<?PHP

$dbConn = mysqli_connect("ServerName(Changed it to post here) ", "UserName", 
"Password", DBname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}else{
    printf("Host information: %s\n", mysqli_get_host_info($mysqli));
    mysqli_close($dbConn);
}
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST['username']);

$password = $_POST['password'];
$vpass = $_POST['verify-password'];
if($password !=== $vpass){
    echo "Your passwords did not match."
}else{
    $userSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (username)
                VALUES ('".$username"')";
    $passSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (password)
                VALUES ('".$password."')";

    $res = mysqli_query($dbConn, $userSQL, $passSQL);

    if ($res === TRUE){
        echo "Account Created";
    }else{
        printf("There was an error creating this account: %s\n", mysqli_error($dbConn));
    }
    mysqli_close($dbConn);
}

?>
```

The problem I am running into is everytime I press the submit button, I get the CANNOT POST newAccount.php error.  What am I doing wrong?  I have been trying to get this to work on my own for the last 2 days.  I even included the database connection code to this file to see if I referenced it wrong in the beginning.

Comment: `!===` is wrong (a syntax error) - should be `!==` . But this isn't the biggest issue with this code. Storing plaintext passwords in your database is a no-no, and you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You should enable error reporting so you can see where things are going wrong. Check out the question I marked as duplicate, specifically the "nothing is seen" part.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the problem causing it not to work in your script, but it seems like that a `;` is missing here

```
if($password !=== $vpass){
    echo "Your passwords did not match."; //<---
}else{
    $userSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (username)
                VALUES ('".$username"')";
    $passSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (password)
                VALUES ('".$password."')";
```

Also,you should not do `<input type=text ...` for your password. Instead, you should use `<input type=password>`

**EDIT:** just found out another mistake that may cause your script not to work...

According to http://php.net/manual/zh/language.operators.comparison.php, there're only !== and != in php,
you should do `if($password !== $vpass)` or `if($password != $vpass)` instead of `if($password != $vpass)`

note: (`sth!==sth` mean `!(sth===sth)` and `sth!=sth` mean `!(sth==sth)`)

**EDIT 2**: as stated by [Robin Zigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8475054/robin-zigmond), you shouldn't save the password with plain text in your database... you could use

```
$passSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (password)
            VALUES ('".password_hash($password)."')";
```

instad to make it safer. When you are logging in, you can use

```
if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $encrypted_password)){
//correct password
}else{
//incorrect password
}
```

to verify the password.

More information can be found on http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
    if($password != $vpass){
    echo "Your passwords did not match."; 
    }else{
    $userSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (username)
            VALUES ('".$username"')";
    $passSQL = "INSERT INTO user_list (password)
            VALUES ('".$password."')";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with the directory.
[You can refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056150/cannot-post-contact-php)

Also, you are sending multiple queries using **mysqli_query()** instead of this use **mysqli_multi_query()** you can find more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)
I hope this will solve your issue.